# Using roots to get original equation

Tags: equation-solving, functions

I have a list of four rules, that I would like to use to find the original polynomial that produced them.

The rules are of the form `{{y -> ...}, {y -> ...}, {y -> ...}, {y -> ...}}` and the equation is `0 == A y^4 +B y^3 + C y^2 + D y + E`.

I am interested in finding the coefficients of the polynomial. The rules are complex, but the coefficients should not be.

I have tried using `SolveAlways`, but I don't believe I am using it correctly.

Comment: You are probably aware of this, but it bears repeating anyway. If you only know the roots, at best you can recover a *family* of polynomials, all multiples of each other: if $a\ y^2+b\ y=0$, then of course $c\ (a\ y^2+b\ y)=0$ as well (for $c\neq0$).

Comment: @user38729, you may use `Rule -> Subtract` to massage the rules.

Comment: Interesting question. Actually, made me think. Does such a polynomial with real coefficients always exist? I mean, given complex roots can we always find a polynomial with real coefficients?

Comment: @BehzadNazari so long as the complex numbers are in conjugate pairs there is a real-coefficient polynomial with those roots.

Comment: @george2079 Yeah, OK now it makes sense and based on that condition I can see my answer always giving real coefficients as well.

Answer (score 5):

```
poly = Total[MapIndexed[#1  x^(First@#2 - 1 ) &, RandomReal[ 1, {5}] ]]
```

> 0.310085 + 0.86543 x + 0.199379 x^2 + 0.630797 x^3 + 0.998793 x^4

```
roots = Solve[poly == 0, x]
```

> {{x -> -0.992501}, {x -> -0.375095}, {x -> 
>      0.368018 - 0.835763 I}, {x -> 0.368018 + 0.835763 I}}

```
result = Times @@ ((x - y) /. roots) // FullSimplify // Expand
```

> 0.310459 + 0.866476 y + 0.19962 y^2 + 0.63156 y^3 + y^4

Of course given only the roots, the polynomial can only be recovered within a multiplicative factor, but we can see this is the same:

```
 Expand[result (poly /. x -> 0)/(result /. y -> 0)]
```

> 0.310085 + 0.86543 y + 0.199379 y^2 + 0.630797 y^3 + 0.998793 y^4

Comment: Alternatively: `Expand[First[Apply[Times, roots /. Rule -> Subtract]]]`

Answer (score 1):

As an alternative, check the method used in the help page of `InterpolatingPolynomial` ([Link1](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/InterpolatingPolynomial.html)). Assuming your rules are defined:

```
rules = {{y -> -1}, {y -> 2}, {y -> -3}, {y -> 4}}
```

Riffle with zeros (the function's value at the roots), add 0,0,1 to the end of the list and partition 2 by 2 to get the coordinates:

```
data = Partition[Join[Riffle[y /. rules, {0}], {0, 0, 1}], 2]
```

Then use `InterpolatingPolynomial`:

```
f[x_] := InterpolatingPolynomial[data, x]
```

which, for this example, results in:

> 1/24 (-4 + x) (-2 + x) (1 + x) (3 + x)

after expanding with `f[x] // Expand` :

> 1 + (7 x)/12 - (13 x^2)/24 - x^3/12 + x^4/24

Plotting this function shows that it passes through all the roots:

[image]

Note that you need 5 points to get the exact interpolating polynomial of order 4. Your system has "an order of freedom" (you have four rules/equations but 5 unknowns/coefficients). I added point (0,1) to make it a closed system.

An example for complex roots in conjugate pairs:

```
rules = {{y -> -1 + 2 I}, {y -> -1 - 2 I}, {y -> -3 I}, {y -> +3 I}}
data = Partition[Join[Riffle[y /. rules, {0}], {0, 0, 1}], 2]
f[x_] := InterpolatingPolynomial[data, x]
```

results in

> 1 + (2 x)/5 + (14 x^2)/45 + (2 x^3)/45 + x^4/45

with the coefficients being:

```
CoefficientList[g = f[x], x]
```

resulting in

> {1, 2/5, 14/45, 2/45, 1/45}

Answer (score 0):

Let's do this for $n=3$, you can always assume that $A=1$:

```
f[y_] := y^2 + B y + C;
roots = {{y -> 1 - I}, {y -> 1 + I}};
S = (f[y] == 0) /. roots
Solve[S, {B, C}] // Simplify
```

Alternatively you can multiply $(y-y_1)..(y-y_n)$ as **george2079** suggests.

Answer (score 0):

Make up some solutions:

```
SeedRandom["MMA.SE"]
sols = {y -> #} & /@ RandomInteger[{-10, 10}, 4]

(*Out: {{y -> 5}, {y -> 6}, {y -> -3}, {y -> -7}} *)
```

Then use them to recover the coefficients of the relative polynomial in $y$ (minus a factor, of course):

```
CoefficientList[Times @@ ((y - #) & /@ (y /. sols)), y]

(* Out: {630, 69, -59, -1, 1} *)
```

Notice that `CoefficientList` returns the coefficients in order of increasing power of $y$, from $y^0$ on up, so the polynomial represented above would be: $y^4-y^3-59\ y^2+69\ y+630$:

```
Solve[y^4 - y^3 - 59 y^2 + 69 y + 630 == 0, y]
(* Out: {{y -> -7}, {y -> -3}, {y -> 5}, {y -> 6}} *)
```